# Custom Query for searching through custom fields

Tags: query, wpdb, dropdown, post-status

Just wondered if someone could spare 5 mins to help me understand where I might be going wrong.

I have a set of custom fields for jobs - I would like to create two drop down menus as a quick search:

Categories for example - IT, Warehousing, Sales...
Salary - 20-30k

I have cobbled together this query -

```
 $myquery = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value, post_status FROM $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->posts WHERE meta_key = %s AND post_status IN ('publish') ", $metakey));
```

With this query, it does populate a drop down list, however, it's still including 'drafts' - in the drop down.

So, how would I exclude 'draft pages' from populating the drop down?

Many thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a join.

```
$myquery = $wpdb->get_col(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta
         INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
         WHERE
             meta_key = %s AND
             post_status IN ('publish')",
        $metakey
    )
);
```

Comment: sorry for my delay, that is brilliant, thank you so much for that, it worked like a charm - I need to look into how to use JOIN!